Detect one or more threshold crossings in a sharply rising signal
Depending on the amplitude, thresholds A, A and B, or A, B and C could be crossed, and I need to indicate (for test purposes with an LED) only the highest threshold crossed. The problem, at least for me, is that when threshold A is crossed, I cannot know if also threshold B or C will be crossed. Because, after threshold A was crossed, I cannot look ahead into the future, my feeling is that I have to take a timestamp and set a flag when threshold A was crossed and then wait for a certain time (how long though?) to see if B or C were also crossed - and only then take action.
Is this how to do it? How do you signal processing experts handle such "multiple threshold indication" issues?


This is an example of a non-causal system. You need to delay the output long enough so that you can make a decision. This sometimes is also referred to a "look ahead".
The amount of the delay will be the longest period over which any LED will on and you need to have to analyze your data (or the physics behind) to determine this minimum delay.

Ok, so I understand that the "timestamp & flag -> wait -> detect higher thresholds until peak -> trigger" approach is correct?
The LEDs can be triggered with a flag and illuminate 200 milliseconds on their own timer, so as not to interrupt the signal processing. Later, audio playback will be used instead. The LEDs are only for cheap and cheerful testing.

If it's for cheerful testing why do you have the requirement that A needs to be off when B comes on? That makes it unnecessarily complicated and leaving on A while B is on looks better. That's how almost all audio meters work.

It's not an audio meter. Instead of LEDs, audio files will be launched. To get the code logic right, I don't want to wire up the entire set-up.

That makes sense. Well, it's simple enough: you just need to delay the output long enough so you can update it when a larger peak comes along. Determining that delay will require statistical analysis of "representative" input signals or the underlying physics. From the a casual glance at your data 30 samples should work and 50 would be plenty, but again that's a data point of one. The downside here is obviously that the sound will (at the earliest) 30 samples after the peak has occurred. Latency can be tricky to manage as it always adds up

50 samples or 100 milliseconds should suffice in this case. That the audio file matching a certain threshold starts playing back with a small delay is no problem in my particular case. I now have to figure out c++ code that does the threshold detection. I guess the program has to idle until the signal crosses thresholdA and then wait 100 milliseconds if the higher thresholds are crossed in that time frame also.
